# ImportError: cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing'

Tags: python, python-import, python-3.7

I have recently started using [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) and [PEP 586](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0586/) to make my code clearer and more accessible. So far everything was ok, but when I wanted to use `Literal` from the package `typing` it appears it couldn't be imported.
What is the most surprising is that PyCharm isn't complaining at all for importing it or using it.

The code I want to use in the end is looking like that :

```py
SomeVar = TypeVar("SomeVar", Literal['choice1'], Literal['choice2'], someType)
```

It would be used in the cases where you can have a string to describe what you want or an already made solution e.g :

```py
def someFunc(my_var: SomeVar = 'choice1'):
    result = []
    if my_var == 'choice1':
        result.append(...)
    else:
        result = my_var
    return result
```

I use an Anaconda environment with Python 3.7.7.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal), `typing.Literal` is only available from Python 3.8 and up.

Comment: Thanks ! What alternative do you advise then ?

Comment: Alternatively (if you don't want to update your Python version), you can use the `Literal` type from the [typing-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) package.

Answer (score 44):

### Using `Literal` in Python 3.8 and later

```
from typing import Literal
```

### Using `Literal` in all Python versions (1)

`Literal` was added to `typing.py` in 3.8, but you can use `Literal` in older versions anyway.

First install `typing_extensions` (`pip install typing_extensions`) and then

```
from typing_extensions import Literal
```

This approach is supposed to work also in Python 3.8 and later.

### Using `Literal` in all Python versions (2)

For completeness, I'm also adding the try-except approach to import `Literal`:

```
try:
    from typing import Literal
except ImportError:
    from typing_extensions import Literal
```

This should also work for all Python versions, given that `typing_extensions` is installed if you're using Python 3.7 or older.

Answer (score 0):

If the developers are using Python 3.8+ but you are want your code to be able to run on older Python versions (like LTS Ubuntu versions) without requiring typing-extensions, then you can just fallback to a string. The people who use your software won't benefit from strict type checking anyway.

```py
import sys

if sys.version_info >= (3, 8):
    from typing import Literal
    MyType = Literal["A", "B", "C"]
else:
    MyType = str
```

You can of course combine this with first trying to fallback to typing_extensions (but then you will have to declare your literal type twice).