# What is the best way to use typing and Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

So, I have recently started playing around with OpenAI, however, when installing and importing the library I have faced such an issue:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'Required' from 'typing' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/typing.py)`

I have checked couple of questions/answers on the problem and as far as I get it that's an "old" Python related issue. At least, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76639778/importerror-cannot-import-name-final-from-typing) a piece of advice. Also, some similar answers are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61206437/importerror-cannot-import-name-literal-from-typing) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76423829/cannot-import-name-ordereddict-from-typing) (see comments).

Given that Python 3.11 is pretty modern, I thought that the issue may be with the version of typing itself. And it is upgradable:

[image]

I thought that the issue may be related to the old `typing` version, however, I can't upgrade:

```
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 3.10.0.0 Requires-Python >=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*, <3.5; 3.7.4.2 Requires-Python >=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*, <3.5
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement typing==3.10.0.0 (from versions: 3.5.0b1, 3.5.0, 3.5.0.1, 3.5.1.0, 3.5.2.2, 3.5.3.0, 3.6.1, 3.6.2, 3.6.4, 3.6.6, 3.7.4, 3.7.4.1, 3.7.4.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for typing==3.10.0.0
```

That looks rather unexpected and I think there may be somewhat else I am missing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure how your environment is set up (it's weird that a `typing` package which resides on your virtual environment is taking precedence over a standard library module), but try running `pip uninstall typing`. [You shouldn't install `typing` at all after Python 3.5](https://pypi.org/project/typing/).

Comment: [`Required` is available from the builtin `typing` module starting in 3.11](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Required).

Comment: @dROOOze had to clean everything up and reinstalled Python, many thx. If you write you recommendations in a form of an answer, I'll be glad to accept, as I have been struggling for several days.